# caching forever, including server reboot and redis to disk feature

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

laravel related:

in the laravel docs we have this written https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache

> Storing Items Forever
>
> The forever method may be used to store an item in the cache
>   permanently. Since these items will not expire, they must be manually
>   removed from the cache using the forget method: Cache::forever('key',
>   'value'); If you are using the Memcached driver, items that are stored
>   "forever" may be removed when the cache reaches its size limit.

what about reboot? memcache will get wiped, so what about 'forever'?

so forever doesn't mean forever, but eventually only until next reboot / crash?

what about redis:

I heard many people praise "IT CAN STORE TO DISK"

well what if the server crashes? is the cache stored currently there as well? does redis take care of that automatically? probably not. So I do not really understand what it is good for. Is the "redis can store to disk" a solution to stated 'forever' problem above? if so, can you explain how?

Comment: If you're using the cache to persist data, then you should consider changing your application design. By definition a cache should be temporary, and should not break the application if it is invalidated. If you're storing something forever in the cache, then it isn't a cache, it's a data store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cache::forever('key', 'value')**
It implies storing value, without any ttl (time-to-live). But when cache size reaches to its assigned size, the previous stored values would be removed.

**Redis**
If you ask about redis. It stores values based on configuration to disk. If server is got crashed, then also you can find old data by restarting it if your disk files are not damaged. Old data from redis is removed only when either size of redis space is full or you have set ttl for values.